# Enable/disable button and color in SwiftUI when new item is added to coredata

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I have a search which gets a list of items from an api. You can download an item, and it will store it in coredata on the iPhone. I want to disable the download button for those items which are already in coredata. How can I check to see if the item is in core data or not while iterating over the list?  This is the code for the button:

```
ForEach (tokenList.indices, id: \.self) { index in

...
                    Button {
                        print("download \(tokenList[index].id)")
                        saveImage(index: index)
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.down.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .padding(.trailing, 10)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                    }
                    .disabled(false)

...
}
```

I would like to set disabled to true .blue to .gray. Do I have to query coredata for each item returned? Is there a better way to do this? It also has to be dynamic that when I saveImage and the record is saved to coredata

I'm new to coredata and swiftui

Comment: What you save in CoreData has an "id", do you save it? If yes, when showing `tokenList`, you can query all items in CoreData that have that "id" (predicate with `IN`), and then you'll know which entity is local already.